# Getting Not Found: / while trying to access Django server from other device in LAN

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to access Django server from outside the device but within LAN. I have exposed my port 8000 for same and then ran -

```
python manage.py runserver 172.30.xxx.xxx:8000
```

Now, while trying to connect from other device using link http://172.30.xxx.xxx:8000 , I end up getting "The connection was reset" in browser. In the Django console it shows "Not Found: /". 
But if I try to access the same link from the device where server is running I am able to access.

What might be the possible glitch here?

Comment: What router are you using?  Are you sure that `172.30.xxx.xxx` is your local address?  Also, there is no need to sensor that information unless that is your public IP.

Comment: @ReinstateMonica Yeah, I guess it is. I ran ifconfig in Ubuntu environment to get that. Though, in most of the cases people said it's of form 192.168.xxx.xxx, but i didn't get any such addresses as of yet. Surprisingly from Windows, its of form 192.168.xxx.xxx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it turns out there was a problem with gateways in LAN. Accessing from same gateway lets me access the site.

Answer (score 0):

To make your development server viewable to other machines on the network on LAN, this procedure works for me

- Run the server like this `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8001`
- Access the server  `192.168.1.xxx:8001`(this IP will be different for you) from another station on the LAN

Comment: I have done almost similar thing. The difference is I get "Not Found: /" while accessing from outside.

Comment: have you added the IP address in `setting.py` at line : `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['192.168.1.xxx','127.0.0.1']`

Comment: Yes, it is. In fact, I am using ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

Comment: Did you try with protocol `https` + your ip?